# How to dispatch C# async function on specific ThreadPool. (Kotlin example provided)

Tags: c#, kotlin, async-await, kotlin-coroutines

I need to translate this Kotlin code on C# using async/await.
Particularly i'm interested how can I create thread pool and execute async method on it.

```
val myThreadPool1 = newFixedThreadPoolContext(1, "myThreadPool1")
val myThreadPool2 = newFixedThreadPoolContext(1, "myThreadPool2")

fun main() = runBlocking {
    f1()
    f2()
}

suspend fun f1() {
    withContext(myThreadPool1) {
        delay(2000)
        println(Thread.currentThread().name)
    }
}

suspend fun f2() {
    withContext(myThreadPool2) {
        delay(1000)
        println(Thread.currentThread().name)
    }
}
```

Comment: Do not "translate". Do what it does "the C# way".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've made an example for you/anyone on how to use the SynchronizationContext to continue awaitable methods on a certain thread. I don't know your C# experience, but this is not at beginners level.

In this example you can see two async methods "interrupting" each other.

I've created a gist for this *(which is a little different)*: [ASyncThread.cs](https://gist.github.com/jvanlangen/fa40f6a2e3b719d066f974ca98065206)

You can use this as a reference..

```
class Program
{
    static async void First()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"{DateTime.Now}| First on Thread: {Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId}");
            await Task.Delay(1000);
        }
    }

    static async void Second()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"{DateTime.Now}| Second on Thread: {Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId}");
            await Task.Delay(500);
        }
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Hello World! on Thread: {Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId}");

        using (var myThread = new AwaitEnabledThread())
        {
            myThread.Post(First);
            myThread.Post(Second);

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

---

Which will result in:

```
Hello World! on thread: 1                           
18-10-2019 12:14:34| First on Thread: 4             
18-10-2019 12:14:34| Second on Thread: 4            
18-10-2019 12:14:35| Second on Thread: 4            
18-10-2019 12:14:35| First on Thread: 4             
18-10-2019 12:14:36| Second on Thread: 4            
18-10-2019 12:14:36| Second on Thread: 4            
18-10-2019 12:14:37| First on Thread: 4             
18-10-2019 12:14:37| Second on Thread: 4            
18-10-2019 12:14:37| Second on Thread: 4            
18-10-2019 12:14:38| First on Thread: 4             
18-10-2019 12:14:38| Second on Thread: 4            
18-10-2019 12:14:38| Second on Thread: 4            
18-10-2019 12:14:39| Second on Thread: 4            
18-10-2019 12:14:39| First on Thread: 4
```

---

```
public class AwaitEnabledThread : SynchronizationContext, IDisposable
{
    // By JvanLangen.
    private class ActionWithState
    {
        public SendOrPostCallback Action { get; set; }
        public object State { get; set; }
    }

    private Task _mainTask;
    private int _mainTaskThreadId;
    private readonly ManualResetEvent _terminate = new ManualResetEvent(false);
    private readonly AutoResetEvent _actionAdded = new AutoResetEvent(false);
    private readonly ConcurrentQueue<ActionWithState> _actions = new ConcurrentQueue<ActionWithState>();

    private void TaskMethod()
    {
        // because this class derives from SynchronizationContext
        SynchronizationContext.SetSynchronizationContext(this); // <-------

        _mainTaskThreadId = Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId;

        var waitHandles = new WaitHandle[] { _terminate, _actionAdded };

        while (WaitHandle.WaitAny(waitHandles) != 0)
            while (_actions.TryDequeue(out var actionWithState))
                actionWithState.Action(actionWithState.State);
    }


    public AwaitEnabledThread()
    {
        _mainTask = Task.Factory.StartNew(TaskMethod, TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning);
    }

    public override void Post(SendOrPostCallback d, object state = null)
    {
        _actions.Enqueue(new ActionWithState { Action = d, State = state });
        _actionAdded.Set();
    }

    public void Post(Action action)
    {
        Post(s => action(), null);
    }

    public override void Send(SendOrPostCallback d, object state = null)
    {
        if (Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId != _mainTaskThreadId)
        {
            _actions.Enqueue(new ActionWithState { Action = d, State = state });
            _actionAdded.Set();
        }
        else
            d(state);
    }

    public void Send(Action action)
    {
        Send(s => action(), null);
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        _terminate.Set();
        _mainTask.Wait();
    }

    public bool Terminated => _terminate.WaitOne(0);
}
```

---

Update: You can even await an Action queued to the thread:

```
public static Task SendASync(this AwaitEnabledThread thread, SendOrPostCallback d, object state = null)
{
    var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<object>();

    thread.Post(s =>
    {
        try
        {
            // execute the delegate
            d(state);
            // return to the previous SynchronizationContext
            tcs.SetResult(null);
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            // return to the previous SynchronizationContext
            tcs.SetException(exception);
        }
    }, tcs);

    return tcs.Task;
}
```

Usage:

```
using (var myThread = new AwaitEnabledThread())
{
    await myThread.SendASync(First);

    // even awaitable actions can be awaited
    await myThread.SendASync(async s =>
    {
        await DoSomethingIO();
        await DoSomethingIOAgain();
    });


    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

The difference is, that the first await affects the current thread. The await in the method is done on the target thread.

Comment: Probably one queue is not enough. Async continuations should have priority over newly scheduled actions.

Comment: There is no difference between a continuation and a regular task for a SynchronizationContext. It's not like a Dispatcher with priorities.

Comment: Lets say that one asynchronous and 9 synchronous actions are posted sequentially to the `AwaitEnabledThread`. All 10 actions have duration 1 sec each. Isn't it strange that the first action will be the last to finish?

Comment: No, the thread can only execute one thing at the time. If you execute long-running code on the UI thread, your button-click-actions are queued behind it. It's about driving a car only backwards, which is possible. Rather drive it forward, whats it's meant to be. It's about using the tools the right way. The developer needs to consider posting synchronous actions to the thread. The time it takes to execute it does not affect the queue. The whole idea of this system is based on small services which are using a dedicated thread to react quick. The link to the Gist is the latest version. Free2use